# Keep VBA code working if I run it from a button in another sheet, or replace the code with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort the date in an excel sheet, I want to click on a button to do this, but button is not at the same sheet
I assigned the macro in a button in the same sheet, it worked very well, but when I moved the button to another sheet it's not working!
what should I edit in this code?

I also attached a screen-shot, maybe there is a formula instead of the this VBA code, or make the VBA code run without click on any buttons
I don't have Office 365, so =FILTER functions is not working

```
Sub SortCC()
'
' SortCC Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Jan_List").Select
    Range("K2:R4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("T2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_List").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "T2:T1241"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("T2:AA1241")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sher Naji,,,, to use that Macro on any other sheet U need to replace the Sheet name `"Jan_List"` with other Sheet name in the code !!

Comment: Thanks @RajeshSinha
Now I know what is the problem, but I can't fix it
The button is linked, and at the same time assigned to macro, when I removed the link it worked, but I need to keep it linked

Comment: Your code relies on the activesheet or activeworkbook.  You select `Jan_List` first so that's the activesheet.  This code pretty much duplicates your first four lines of code:  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_List").Range("K2:R4").End(xlDown).Copy`.  This only copies cell K4 though.  Manually highlight `K2:R4` and press `Ctrl+Down` and you'll select `K4`.  Have a read of this post:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in a normal module - **not** in a `Sheet` or `ThisWorkbook`.
Add a button to each sheet you want to sort and connect it to the macro.

```
Public Sub SortCC()

    'You want the code to run on the sheet that has the button.
    'To manually push the button the correct sheet must be active.
    'So in this case we can use ActiveSheet.  Note this is the only Sheet reference in the code.
    With ActiveSheet
        'Assumes Column R (18) has a value in last row of data.
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range("K2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp))
        
        DataRange.Copy
        .Range("T2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        'We could figure out the new range the same way we did with the old one,
        'but seeing as it's the same size as the original and one column across
        'we can just use offset to figure it out.
        Dim NewDataRange As Range
        Set NewDataRange = DataRange.Offset(, DataRange.Columns.Count + 1)
    
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            
            'Sorting on first column of NewDataRange so have resized it to one column.
            'For another column use, for example, .Offset(,1).Resize(,1) for second column.
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=NewDataRange.Resize(, 1), _
                                  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                  Order:=xlDescending, _
                                  DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange NewDataRange
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
                              
    End With
    
End Sub
```